# Getting "Authorization has been denied for this request" from Postman when trying to consume simple .NET web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'll try to be specific.

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpV7yp-TXFk&t=4s) which seems to be very easy and specific. Web Api security seems to work flawless out of the box in that video. To test my api, I am using Postman rest client

My problem is that, I get my access token through PostMan and everything is fine until I try to call methods under the [Authorized] annotation. If I try to do that, I receive a piece of Json with the message:

"Authorization has been denied for this request"

I am choosing "authorization" from the "headers" option in PostMan and copy/pasting my token.

What I am doing wrong??? The example in the video tutorial work flawless.

Here is my startup class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DFP_API.Startup))]

namespace DFP_API
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the content of ConfigureAuth method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using DFP_API.Providers;
using DFP_API.Models;

namespace DFP_API
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //    consumerKey: "",
            //    consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //    appId: "",
            //    appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            //{
            //    ClientId = "",
            //    ClientSecret = ""
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

And just in case, my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DFP_API
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            //Esta línea quita el XML
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();

            //Esta línea identa el JSON
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            //Esta línea convierte el JSON a CamelCase
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate your help!! Thank you!

Comment: Because you are using Cookie authentication, you need to add the token you receive back from the login path to the request that requires authorization into a cookie. Not sure how to do that in Postman. Try google it.

Comment: So I need to send the authorization token through a cookie instead of using the headers. That's what you mean right?

Comment: @Michael well, I found this documentation (https://www.getpostman.com/docs/interceptor_cookies) but how do I know the name of the cookie that I must send?

Comment: I have not tried to use CookieAuthentication, but according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.cookiename(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieName) the default cookie name is `.AspNet.Cookies`. You can of course change this with `CookieAuthenticationOptions`. If you don't want to use CookieAuthentication, but use the header instead, take a look at this article: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: @Michael I sent a cookie named ".AspNet.Cookies" with the token with not avail. I also tried "Authorization" and "Bearer" names. Thank you for the documentation though. I am thinking to just switch to token based authorization. This is also a nice video to do so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMA69bVv0U8&t=2402s